# Submit value directly from Eloqua email

Tags: email, eloqua

I want to send out an email using Eloqua that has links in it.  These links would refer to our microsite on Eloqua.  Based on the link that is clicked, I want a field to be updated in the Eloqua database.

For example:

```
Are you planning to attend the open house?
        Yes     No
```

The Yes and No, would be links back to an Eloqua landing page without a form.  I do not want the user to take multiple steps in order to gather the information.  Can this be done (how?) using some service on Eloqua?

Something like:
https://microsite.domain.com%email=customer@theirdomain.com&attending=true

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by using [blind form submits](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/marketingcs_gs/OMCAA/Help/Forms/Tasks/CreatingBlindFormSubmitLinks.htm).

Essentially you would create one form with two fields to capture the email address and their attendance status. Based upon the form and field names, you can concatenate a url, using an email address field merge for the email parameter, and you can hard code a literal "true" or "false" for each button/link. Please refer to the linked documentation for full instructions.

Processing steps would likely store the attendance in a related CDO, or be saved directly on the contact record. Another processing step could direct them to a confirmation page.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give that a shot!